# Matlab Graphics in GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

How can we export the 3-D graphics of the metal rod that i have modelled in CAD software into the GUI of matlab?

How can we control the coordinates of these rods using slider in matlab or through user controlled by putting the co-ordinate in the edit box and the changes can be visualized or observed in the graphics imported from CAD model simultaneously as the user changes the value?

Please help me and give me suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: At least tell us the export format of the 3D model.

Comment: I have done modelling in Solidworks and it provides different export format options e.g. iges,.prt.stp etc. I have converted it to image file i.e. ".jpg". Please tell me how to proceed with my problem.

Comment: Once you convert this to a jpg, you certainly won't be able to do "3D stuff" anymore. Search the web for "matlab iges import", you'll find a few FileExchange contributions for that ... (haven't tried the others).

Comment: OK, I will try that and when it has imported how it will be imported to GUIDE. Which option will help   me and visualize the changes in model when change through the edit box simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to export 3D model in ASCII STL format in your CAD software? If so, there is an import function available on Matlab File Exchange:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30923-fast-stl-import-function

I have personally used this method for weld defects and linking between Matlab and aRTist - it worked well. I'm aware this doesn't solve the problem completly, but belive importing file into Matlab is a good first step.